# Can only snap into predefined areas

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, shortcuts, aero

So I've been experiencing a really weird problem since a couple of days (on Windows 8). First of all, the Windows + arrow combination won't snap my applications to the left or right anymore. They won't do anything at all (tried changing the setting ‘Prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen’, didn't change anything at all)

Second: when I try to move my open window onto another location, Windows decides differently and forces the open window into either a red box or a yellow one as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/hPfkc6K.jpg]

I have tried to find someone that already posted about this on Superuser, but couldn't find anyone with related issues, as it's really hard to describe the problem..

Comment: You've got a lot of tools in your tray. Maybe one of them is some sort of window-manager-helper? Tried this on new temporary windows account?

Comment: @LogicDaemon I tried disabling all the programs that were running in the tray, didn't work. On guest accounts (or any other account) everything works fine.

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with any Windows settings that can achieve this behaviour, so I bet this is some 3rd party software. It's not matter if software is in tray or just hidden. Look what you've got in Startup (`Ctrl+Shift+Esc` for Task manager, Startup tab) for any clues.

Comment: let me turn it into answer and mark it good one then :)

Comment: also barely it's malware, because usually malware tries to hide instead of managing windows in seemingly sane-in-some-cases way. This is why antivirus ignored it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've said in comments, this behavior isn't case for other users.

I'm not familiar with any Windows settings that can achieve this behaviour, so I bet this is some 3rd party software.

It's not matter if software is in tray or just hidden. Look what you've got in Startup (Ctrl+Shift+Esc for Task manager, Startup tab) for any clues.

Comment: I was wrong about the problem in the comments as it ain't malware. The real problem was caused by the Dell Display Manager. For some reason it allows you to 'Easy Arrange'. Just disable it and the problem will be solved.  Thanks again for your time. http://i.imgur.com/RxGsc5P.png

Comment: good you found it :)